# How can I create a VHOST redirect that doesn't pass pages and sub directories

Tags: apache, redirect, vhosts

I know that if I put the following in I get a 301 redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.foo.com
Redirect 301 / http://www.bar.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that this will also redirect `www.foo.com/cart.php` to `www.bar.com/cart.php`. What I am looking for is how can I redirect `www.foo.com/*` to just `www.bar.com/` and not the page or sub directory?

I am wanting to do this via the vhost file and not using .htaccess file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bar.com$1 [R=301,L]
```